# select rows first that has a match id in a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `temporary table` that contains a list of id's and what I want is when I query from my main table those id's that is in my `temporary table` will be shown first in the result.

Example:

This is the data from temporary table:

```
ID
--
7
5
3
```

Then when I query in my main table I want the `ID's` from the temporary table to show first in my result.

```
ID
--
7 -- from temp table
5 -- from temp table
3 -- from temp table
1
2
4
6
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You need to show your code if you want assistance. And sample data, and expected results.

Comment: sorry about that, I added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple left join should behave the way you want:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM main_table m
LEFT JOIN temp_table t
    ON m.id = t.id
ORDER BY
    t.id DESC;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause I used should work, and those records in the `main_table` which did *not* match to anything in the `temp_table` should be pushed to the bottom of the result set.  You could also add another level of sorting if you wanted to.